# Retain smartcast when creating custom extension

Tags: kotlin

I currently have to write

```
val myList: List<Int>? = listOf()
if(!myList.isNullOrEmpty()){
    // myList manipulations
}
```

Which smartcasts myList to no non null. The below do not give any smartcast:

```
if(!myList.orEmpty().isNotEmpty()){
    // Compiler thinks myList can be null here
    // But this is not what I want either, I want the extension fun below
}

if(myList.isNotEmptyExtension()){
    // Compiler thinks myList can be null here
}

private fun <T> Collection<T>?.isNotEmptyExtension() : Boolean {
    return !this.isNullOrEmpty()
}
```

Is there a way to get smartCasts for custom extensions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is solved by [contracts](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.contracts/index.html) introduced in [Kotlin 1.3](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/whatsnew13.html#contracts).

Contracts are a way to inform the compiler certain properties of your function, so that it can perform some static analysis, in this case enable smart casts.

```
import kotlin.contracts.ExperimentalContracts
import kotlin.contracts.contract

@ExperimentalContracts
private fun <T> Collection<T>?.isNotEmptyExtension() : Boolean {
    contract {
       returns(true) implies (this@isNotEmptyExtension != null)
    }
    return !this.isNullOrEmpty()
}
```

You can refer to the source of `isNullOrEmpty` and see a similar contract.

```
contract {
    returns(false) implies (this@isNullOrEmpty != null)
}
```

Comment: This kind of code seems to not compile for me: stackoverflow.com/questions/75178295/… I have code snipits here. It works when I use a traditional function, but not an extension.