# Kotlin smart cast not working with extensions functions

Tags: kotlin

I am trying check nullable object with extension function, but smart casting not work after calling this function.

```kotlin
fun <T> T?.test(): T = this ?: throw Exception()

val x: String? = "x"
x.test()
x.length // Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type String?
```

Is it a Kotlin bug? If not, why there is no implicit casting?

Comment: Your null test is hidden behind your function. For this to work, your function has to employ a contract. This function is redundant to the `!!` operator, which would provide you the smart cast.

Comment: It's because the extension function returns the non nullable object, but you're not reassigning it to `x`. If you had `var x` and you reassign it as `x = x.test()`, then it would work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57670014/retain-smartcast-when-creating-custom-extension related

Answer (score 2):

As @Madhu Bhat mentioned  in comment above, your variable 'x' is still nullable.
You may use your function simply like this:

```
x.test().length
```

Otherwise  you can check for null by following inline function and then perform any functions directly on the variable. (Note the usage of 'contract' and annotations '@ExperimentalContracts')

```
@ExperimentalContracts
fun <T> T?.notNull(): Boolean {

    contract {
        returns(true) implies (this@notNull != null)
    }

    return this != null
}
```

Now you can use this function like this

```
if(x.notNull()){
  x.length
}
```

But its not seems so useful if your using this function just to check nullability.

Check here to know more  about Kotlin [contracts](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2018/kotlin-contracts/)

Comment: This kind of code seems to not compile for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75178295/kotlin-contracts-not-working-for-null-check-in-extension-function

I have code snipits here.  It works when I use a traditional function, but not an extension.